# SQL Join Issues Microsoft Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to write some code in SQL, but it keeps coming up with a syntax error regarding the join, and I can't work out why.

```
SELECT `COUNTRY$`.country_name, `PARTNER$`.partner_name,  count(member_id) 
FROM `Member$`
Left Join `COUNTRY$`
ON `MEMBER$`.country_id=`COUNTRY$`.country_id
lEFT jOIN  `PARTNER$`
on `MEMBER$`.partner_ID = `PARTNER$`.partner_ID
Group By country_name,Partner_name
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Not that it's causing your problem, but your code should be more consistent. You're switching between UPPERCASE, UPPERlower, lowerUPPER, and lowercase for SQL Keywords. Like 'Left Join' and 'lEFT jOIN' and 'ON' and 'on'. It just seems messy.

Answer (score 1):

May have something to do with how your table names are in 'thisFormat$'. Also you did not specify which table member_id was coming and group by also doesn't specify which table country_name, partner_name was from.

Try putting aliases on the tablenames and see if that eliminates the problem

```
SELECT c.country_name, p.partner_name, count(m.member_id)
FROM `Member$` m
left join `COUNTRY$` c on c.country_id = m.country_id
left join `PARTNER$` p on p.partner_id = m.partner_id
GROUP BY c.country_name, p.partner_name
```